# What is the setting for Project finder to avoid to search certain files/dirs?

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm using the CTAGs package and it generates two files `.tags` and `.tags_sorted_by_file` with Sublime Text 2.

So when I do a project search (CMD + SHIFT + F), how do I set the project finder not to search in those two files or directories??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMD+,`

Add

```
    "file_exclude_patterns": [
        ".tags",
        ".tags_sorted_by_file"
    ],
```

to the root object.

Answer (score 0):

When you search (CMD+SHIFT+F), you can specify the "Exclude Filter" in the menu.
For you case you can set "Where:" to something like

`-.tags,your_project_path`

You can also edit your project file (you should see the project file in the root path of your project) so the tag files will not show in the sidebar also.
Just add the `file_exclude_patterns` in the `folders` section should do the trick.